# /usr/share/python/debian_defaults Ubuntu / Mac equivalent

Tags: mac, python, version

After a lot of trial and error, I upgraded my system's default version of Python on Ubuntu.  The `debian_defaults` file was part of the solution on Linux.

Now I am trying to do the same thing on my Mac... I downloaded and installed Python with the correct $ commands, and now I have to (before a few other commands) change the version argument in `debian_defaults`...

The problem is, there is not a `debian_defaults` on a Mac, and there is not even a Python folder on Mac... Where is the equivalent file on Mac where I can set the version of Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just symlink the new pythonx.y to python in the /bin/bash folder, and also symlink the new python.framework to the existing alias 'current' (in the frameworks folder.